# About Reverse Animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container, game-development

I'm currently making a game that replays the player in reverse.
Is there a way to make the player animation play in reverse smoothly?
For now, animation is recorded every 0.02 seconds, and when reverse playback is required, the recorded values ​​are loaded and played back in sequence.
However, this won't transition smoothly between animations.
Please let me know if you know anything. thank you
(Please note that I used a translator because my English is a bit immature.)

Answer (score 0):

You can record the every single frame instead and make sure to store the timestamp for each frame, then when playing back you can lerp between the data of the two closest frame to the time you want. If you need it to work somewhat well with physics you'll have to store it based on FixedUpdate instead, and reverse the physics calculations too.

Though this might require a lot of memory if the framerate is high, something similar to what you already have, recording every 0.02 seconds, with added lerping might be enough. You can also try using vsync to have a more consistent framerate.